# "would" and "will" after "when" for generalization

Tags: meaning, time, would, when

I need help, a second eye to proofread the following:

*"This method precludes an instance when the user has/will have their device broken."*

**AND:**

*"This method precluded an instance when the user had/would have their device broken."*

Which one is correct or "more correct"?

The more I think about it, the more probable seems to have every option correct despite the case of a time clause (c.f. *I don't know when he will come home* AND *I don't know when he comes home*). Something tells me, however, that neither *will* nor *would* work here as the sentences could suit a manual, a general rule as we see in if-clauses: if + simple presence, + simple presence (If you heat up water, it boils.), or the like... Please help!

Comment: Are you talking about an instance that has happened or might happen?

Comment: That might happen

Comment: "When will I see you again?"  "When would be a good time to meet?"

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: '... [modal] have their device broken' is surely punctive, perhaps 'might be visited by a thug who breaks their device'. Do you mean 'This method prevents a situation where the user is struggling with a broken device'? Or do you mean 'does not include' or 'will cater for', which 'preclude' doesn't mean?

Comment: More the first one: _This method prevents a situation where the user is struggling with a broken device_